# arithmetic coding,is there an easy way to use the leftover capacity in a word?

Tags: algorithm, compression, bit-manipulation

Given 26 letters in the English language, I can encode a letter in 5 bits, with values from 0 to 25 being used, and 26 through 31 wasted.

Somewhat slower, but slightly better compression would encode as base 26.

At 5 bits per letter, 12 letters fit into a 64-bit word.
Using base 26, 13 letters fit into a 64-bit word, but there is still some waste capacity.

26^13 = 2.48115e+18
2^64 = 1.844e+19

Is there any reasonably compact way to use the extra bit or two instead of wasting it to pack 13.5 words in each 64-bit number? I can't think of an easy way, and if it takes huge amounts of code, or takes far longer, I'm not sure it will be worth it, but I'm curious if there's an elegant solution.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Do the same thing with 128-bit arithmetic, and you'll get 27 letters. There will only be about one wasted bit, or about 0.04 bits per letter. As opposed to almost six wasted bits putting 13 letters in 64 bits twice (0.2 bits per letter lost).

Many C compilers provide a 128-bit integer, making this easy. With that, you don't need to hand code any multiple-precision arithmetic yourself. GCC and Clang have `unsigned __int128`.

If you're willing to assemble a stream of bits in the output, then do the above, but write 127 bits to the output for each 27 letters, instead of 128 bits. Then you will be wasting only 0.003 bits per letter.

At the end, you don't need to write all 127 bits if there is not a multiple of 27 letters. Code the first letter into the least significant bits and write the least significant bits of each 127-word first, most-significant bits last. Then pad the characters with your symbol 0 (an `'a'` I presume), and the high bits of the 127 will be zeros. Only send enough bits to cover the last letter.

If you are writing this to bytes, you can be left with an ambiguity as to whether a final `'a'` is part of the message or not. One solution would be to send a single bit at the start of the message with whether it contains an even or odd number of letters.

An alternative would be to use a flat Huffman code. This assumes that all letters are equally likely, which is the assumption made in the base-26 coding above as well. Code the first six letters with four bits each (`0000`, `0001`, ..., `0101`), and then the remaining 20 letters with five bits each (`01100`, `01101`, ..., `11111`). This is a prefix code, so whether the symbol is four or five bits can be determined by the decoder from the first four bits. Each letter will be coded in an average of 4.77 bits, vs. the theoretical optimum of 4.70 bits. So a loss of 0.07 bits per letter. Not as good as the 0.003 bits per letter lost in the 127-bit scheme, but much faster to encode and decode, if speed is an objective. This can leave you with the same ambiguity in the last byte, so precede it with one bit with the length modulo 2.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you gave an answer to your own question in the title -- you can use arithmetic coding and get arbitrarily close to the log<sub>2</sub>(26) bits/character.

I think that's a little complicated, though, and there will be a couple bits wasted at the end.  It probably isn't justified.

I think you should probably stick to your base-26 idea, but instead of encoding as many characters as you can into 64 bits, encode 7 characters into 33 bits.

7 characters uses log<sub>2</sub>(26)*7 = 32.903 bits, so you will waste less than 0.1 bits per 33-bit word.